# enhancing a c++ function to take stringstream in addition to std::string

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Using stringstream after << as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519829/c-using-stringstream-after-as-parameter)

I've a function like this

```
print(const std::string& message);
```

How can I wrap it at some other place, such that I can use, say

```
print2("some message"<<object);
```

this should internally call the above function.

Comment: Have you thought about wrapping the whole stream with this operator `template<typename _Ty> const MyStream& operator<<(_In_ const _Ty& lpcvVal) const;`?

Comment: a very close match and some very related information. but, not exactly similar, as I believe I'll have to overload the operator<< for std::string.

Comment: IMO you shouldn't use `operator<<` for this. A string literal can't be left-shifted or even output-to, so this is a new meaning for `operator<<`. Inventing brand new meanings for existing operators should happen very rarely and only to create a significantly better idiom. Tempting though it sometimes is to use operator overloads to avoid thinking of function names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a C++11 solution using variadic templates:

```
void print(std::string const & message);   // your original function as before

void print2(std::istringstream & iss)
{
    print(iss.str());
}

template <typename T, typename ...Rest>
void print2(std::istringstream & iss, T && t, Rest &&... rest)
{
     iss << std::forward<T>(t);
     print2(iss, std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}

template <typename ...Args>
void print2(Args &&... args)
{
     std::istringstream iss;
     print2(iss, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Usage:

```
print2("Some message", x, foo, "text");
```

An interface with a variable number of arguments is neater and more direct than an awkward use of shift operators in the function call, since the latter requires you to create a stream object explicitly, and you'd then need to deal with the stream's low-level `rdbuf` directly, and that approach wouldn't have the original, no-argument version as a special case.

Comment: "in C++11 we pass by value" - am I missing something important, or have you assumed that the function will *only* be called with a temporary (or with `move`), and so you've gone ahead and pessimized the case of a caller who wants to pass a value and use it again later?

Comment: @SteveJessop: I've assumed that `print2` will be the exclusive new interface... but you're right, the const-reference wouldn't be any worse. I'll change it.

Comment: Ah, got it. I wonder whether there are short, common terms that disambiguate between "wrap and replace the interface" and "extend the interface by wrapping".

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yeah, if the question had more details, we could probably make further suggestions... as it stands, I would always strive to keep complexity at a minimum, and thus if I need a wrapper, the wrapper should encompass the original functionality fully.

Comment: Makes sense. I just made the opposite assumption, that the wrapper is intended for use in new code, but that there exists old code that won't be overhauled. Maybe I've been permanently scarred by the fact that my first job was writing libraries, and backward-compatibility was king. So I'm even scared of introducing an extra string copy to existing code...

Comment: @SteveJessop: Right, that's a very good point. I wasn't awake enough, and definitely over-zealous with the by-value passing. That one should be reserved *only* for cases where the function needs a local copy. (But we don't know what the OP is doing inside `print`.) Thanks!

Comment: In C++20 I am currently passing to *istringstream* like: `std::istringstream iss{ std::forward<std::string>(str) };`

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly create a template `operator<<` which returns a stringstream

```
template<class T>
std::stringstream operator<<(const char* c_str, T t)
{
   std::stringstream tmp;

   tmp << t;

   return tmp;
}
```

then you would need to define

```
void print2(std::stringstream sstream)
{
    print(sstream.str())
}
```

You could also overload the original print method, so that you could equally well write

```
print("something"<<some_obj);
```

Comment: Why do you pass *c_str to the function overloaded?

Comment: Because it is not a member function so you need to pass in both of its arguments.