# Why is a rvalue string stream working in this context but not an lvalue?

Tags: c++, string, std

I noticed that I could do some quick and dirty translation of a narrow to a wide string by doing the following:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    wcout << (wstringstream{} << "This works.\n").str();
    wstringstream ss{};
    wcout << (std::move(ss) << "This works too.\n").str();
    return 0;
}
```

But if I replaced the rvalue `wstringstream` with an lvalue, it doesn't work:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    wstringstream ss{};
    wcout << (ss << "This doesn't work. :(\n").str();
    return 0;
}
```

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12519829/5754656 and [LWG1203](https://wg21.link/LWG1203)

Comment: `ss` calls the inherited `basic_ostream& operator<<( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb )`, and `wstringstream{} << "This works.\n"` calls the free operator template `template< class Ostream, class T >
Ostream&& operator<<( Ostream&& os, const T& value );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the working examples the type is `std::basic_stringstream` which has a `str()` method and comes form an rvalue template of the `<<` operator:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&& std::operator<< <std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >, char [13]>(std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&&, char const (&) [13])
```

Whereas in the non-working it is `std::basic_ostream` which does not have a `str()` method and is from the inherited class operator overload.

```
std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >& std::operator<< <wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >&, char const*)
```

Comment: Yes, I could guess that, but why?  And I guess this is a bug in [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/3e120073) then?

Comment: Oh, I guess it's because the class `operator<<` isn't a `const` or a `&&`, so it goes to the free template. That makes sense.